# How do I setup a phone that automatically presses 9 whenever it gets a call?

Tags: automation, phone

I am looking to automate a process where I need to press 9 on the keypad whenever I get a call from a certain number, though if this is done with some sort of server phone, I don't care who calls; just press 9 and hang up.

In terms of phone service, I've considered using an app such as TextPlus where I can receive unlimited calls, but how can I tell the app to press 9 whenever it gets a call?

I am wondering how I should go about this? Is there software for this? This needs to run 24/7, so I assume I'll need to have a server somewhere. Any thoughts?

Comment: Android or Apple?

Comment: Its entirely unclear what you are asking. Details matter.

Comment: Please don't change the meaning of your question; I've rolled back [your changes](https://superuser.com/revisions/1491429/2). If you have a new one, ask a new one if it has not been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering machine or voicemail prompt, and record the DTMF 9 as part of the outgoing message.

Set the answering machine or voicemail to "answer only" so you don't get lots of empty messages.

If you're using something like Asterisk you will probably be able to route calls from the specific number to a specific OGM with the DTMF tone.